# Creating a widget that displays the content of a page

Tags: widgets, query

I have a page that displays information from a query (I placed the output of the query in a custom page template and have the information display that way). How can I put this information into a sidebar widget? Do I need to pull it from the page, or is there a widget that allows you to put a dynamic query inside?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you hard-coded your custom query directly in the page template, then you're going to need to duplicate that custom query in a custom Widget.

On the other hand, if you've abstracted the custom query (either into a template-part file, or better yet, a custom function), then you can simply include the template-part file or custom function in your custom Widget.

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this using the Text Widget.

Enabling shortcodes for it:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode', 11);
```

And then, as Chip Bennett points out, using a custom shortcode function that will output your custom query.

Comment: IMHO, this is far more complex (and potentially dangerous) than simply creating a custom Widget...

Comment: @ChipBennett - I see... so a better answer depends on the OP showing us his Query, no?

Comment: **absolutely** :)